# Neo4j - Create relationship using composite key table

Tags: neo4j, cypher

hi I have these following nodes: `A:lineitem`, `B:parts`, `C:Suppliers` and another node `D:Partsupp` (combination of parts and supplier with composite keys) now I have to relate `:lineitem` with `:parts` using properties of `:partsupp`, then `:parts` to `:supplier`. Also, there is no common key between `:parts` and `:supplier`. How can I create relationship?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a small representative data set.

Comment: @Dave Bennett https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e4ddce9f799c3a96c04c2e4c83d736f4d1aeb3a9/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6232636275636b65742f747063685f736368656d612e706e67  please check the url this is the data model i need to create in neo4j... I stuck between the lineitem,part,partsupp and supplier....also, i'am writing the queries in Cypher not using Java.

Comment: Check out https://neo4j.com/blog/rdbms-neo4j-etl-tool/ for an explanation on how to make a "translation" from a relational to a graph model.

Answer (score 0):

The `PARTSUPP` table (in the original [relational data model](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e4ddce9f799c3a96c04c2e4c83d736f4d1aeb3a9/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6232636275636b65742f747063685f736368656d612e706e67)) is simply for associating each supplier with the parts that it offers. Therefore, each row in that table should be turned into a neo4j relationship (not a node) between the relevant `Part` and `Supplier` nodes, and its non-key fields should become properties of that relationship.

Here is a partial sample data model:

#### Nodes

```
(p:Part {key: ..., name: '...', ...})
(s:Supplier {key: ..., name: '...', ...})
(l:LineItem {lineNumber: ..., quantity: ..., ...})
```

#### Relationships

```
(s)-[:OFFERS {availQty: ..., supplyCost: ..., comment: '...'}]->(p)
(s)<-[:FROM_SUPPLIER]-(l)-[:FOR_PART]->(p)
```